# EntityFramework 6 - Transient.collection Exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I have the below Database-First model:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Partial Public Class User
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Username As String
    Public Property Password As String
    Public Property IsDisabled As Boolean
    Public Property IsSuper As Boolean
    Public Property MustChangePassword As Boolean
    Public Property Notes As String

    Public Overridable Property UserPermissions As ICollection(Of UserPermission) = New HashSet(Of UserPermission)

End Class
```

And the DB Context

```
Partial Public Class Entities
Inherits DbContext

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("name=Entities")
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
    Throw New UnintentionalCodeFirstException()
End Sub

.
.
.
Public Overridable Property Users() As DbSet(Of User)
.
.
.
End Class
```

Whenever I run the below query:

```
dim ent = New Entities()
result = (From u In ent.Users
          Where u.ID = ID
          Select u).SingleOrDefault()
```

I get the following error:

> 'Users' is not a member of 'Transient.collection[Conso_Model.Entity(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'. To extract a property of a collection element, use a sub-query to iterate over the collection. Near escaped identifier, line 1, column 12.

Any clue?

Comment: Can you try `result = ent.Users.Where(Func(u) u.ID = ID).SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: Tried it, same exception

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!
There is another EF class named Entity with pluralized collection name 'Entities' (similar to Database Context class)!

How stupid VB compiler didn't fire any warning about this!